# PHP Regex to get text between 2 words with numbers

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to get the string between two words in a entire string:

Ex.:

My string:

...'Total a Facturar 123,061 221,063 ***26,860161,16080,580310,760*** 358,297 Recepcionado'...

I'm using

```
/(?<=Total a Facturar )(.*?) Recepcionado/
```

I need the highlighted characters (***26,860161,16080,580310,760***)
and i get `221,061 221,063 26,860161,16080,580310,760 358,297 Recepcionado` with my pattern.

The numbers of the string are always different, i need the numbers that are together without a space.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the entire string: [eval.in/802292](http://eval.in/802292)

Comment: does your string contains `***` ??

Comment: @hassan Current input was like this..

Comment: @SahilGulati it isn't clear, in theory **123,061** this is "a numbers together without a space", the OP need to clarify more

Comment: @hassan I think it is clearly mentioned as written  _I need the highlighted characters (26,860161,16080,580310,760)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be helpful

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rhV8Iu/1) or [**Regex demo 2**](https://regex101.com/r/rhV8Iu/2)

**Regex:** `(?:\d+(?:\,\d+){2,})`
For above question you can also use it like this `(?:\d+(?:\,\d+){4})`

> **1.** `(?:\d+)` this will match digits one or more.
>
> **2.** `(?:\,\d+){2,}` Adding this in expression will match patterns like `,` and `digits` `{2,}` for `2` or more than `2` times.

**PHP code:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/802194)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string = "Total a Facturar 123,061 221,063 26,860161,16080,580310,760 358,297 Recepcionado";
preg_match("#(?:\d+(?:\,\d+){2,})#", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: It works but my entire string has a similar pattern before the match that i need and it returns me the other. Here is a link with the full text 

https://eval.in/802292

Comment: yes for getting multiple matches you have to use preg_match_all.. i answered your question with above input string in mind..you are welcome friend... :) If you have any further issues just let me know.. i will help you out...